# Updating SQL database value in PHP script

Tags: php, sql

I have an IPN script that is doing some work on the amount of a payment received, and when a certain amount is received, it is updating their license code in the database after verifying it with PayPal's IPN service.

This SQL isn't right, it's not updating.  The rest of my code is fine because it sends an email, but where's the SQL error at?  It's really late and I'm spacing out...

```
if ($amt == "77.00")
    { 
     mysql_query("UPDATE login_users SET license_code = 3 WHERE username = ". $username ."") or die(mysql_error()); 
      // Change license code in database
    }
```

Comment: You forgot quotes around `" . $username . "`. You have to put them if you want your variable to be considered as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the user name if it's a string.

```
 WHERE username = '". $username ."'
```

Also make sure `$username` is properly sanitized:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(... wherever the value is coming from ...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pekka, your answer worked straight out of the box.  And yes, regardless that it's been verified with Paypal I should probably do that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Put `SET` before `WHERE` and add single quotes around username

```
"UPDATE login_users SET license_code = 3 WHERE username = '". $username ."'";
```

Comment: Just updated my code above, Dreamweaver says no syntax errors with mine, had to add a trailing " to yours because it's appending a variable, but it's not updating still for some reason...